# why isn't my int saving correctly? (java)

Tags: java

I have a problem:

I'm using an input (string) that I want to save into an int. I want to use that int in another class, but  the int is still 0 after my user input. The code is below. I want to use the int fsize in another class. I want to use it with `getFsize()` but if I use it in the other class it says `fsize = 0`.

```
public class MineSweeper {
    private boolean gameOn = true;
    int fsize;
    int bpercent;
    ConsoleIO io = new ConsoleIO();

    // start getters and setters
    public int getFsize() {
        return fsize;
    }

    public void setFsize(int fsize) {
        this.fsize = fsize;
    }

    public int getBpercent() {
        return bpercent;
    }

    public void setBpercent(int bpercent) {
        this.bpercent = bpercent;
    }

    // end getters and setters
    // while (gameOn = true) {

    public void startGame() {
        io.writeOutput("Welkom bij het spelletje  Mijnenveger!");
        io.writeOutput("Probeer alle mijnen te vinden in het mijnen veld.");
    }

    public void fieldSize() {
        io.writeOutput("Geef de grootte van het veld (5-20):");
        // read the input from the console
        String input1 = io.readInput();
        if (input1.matches("[0-9]+")) {
            this.fsize = Integer.parseInt(input1);
            if (this.fsize > 20 || this.fsize < 5) {
                System.out
                        .println("*** De grootte moet tussen 5 en 20 liggen! ***");
                fieldSize();
            } else {
                System.out.println(this.fsize);
                }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Vul wel een enkel getal in tussen 5 en 20!");
            fieldSize();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you call this class and its methods?

Comment: i call it in the main class:
 MineSweeper sweep = new MineSweeper();
  sweep.startGame();
  sweep.fieldSize();
  sweep.bombPercentage();
  Field field = new Field();
  field.printField();

Comment: i changed it to static int fsize; and it worked!! thank you so much! :D

Comment: and i deleted my comments rofl

Comment: I can't see why, from the code shown, this wouldn't work, nor why making `fsize` `static` would fix the problem. You probably don't need it to be `static`, do you? Did you show all of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You want `Integer.valueOf(input1)` in place of `Integer.parseInt(input1)`.

Comment: what difference would it make in this case?

Comment: I do not see how changing fsize to static would help, there is no code that you posted that suggests that there would be multiple instances. are you sure you understand what changing that field to static means? you are probably setting the value of the field from another instance, and the static conveniently fixes it. you still have a bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Integer object as you would use the integer primitive type. This is because of Java's Autoboxing, where it seamlessly converts the int to Integers.

You could just say `somevalue = input1;` or `input1 = somevalue;` without casting or calling other methods.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the same instance of the class MineSweeper? When you declare the attribute fsize it starts by default with the value 0. If you don't call the method fieldSize() to assign the input value to the attribute fsize for every instance you start it will be always 0